# Infinite recursive box in 2d array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, recursion, drawing

I want to implement a method draw() which takes 3 parameters width, height, padding and return an 2d array representing the following shape:

```
[
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],
[2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],
[2,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,2],
[2,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,2],
[2,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,2],
[2,0,0,2,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2],
[2,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,2],
[2,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,2],
[2,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,2],
[2,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,2],
[2,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,2],
[2,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,2],
[2,0,0,2,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2],
[2,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,2],
[2,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,2],
[2,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,2],
[2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],
[2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
]
```

- Shape is centered inside each other, means `Padding` is divided by 2 each side 
  (eg: Padding = 8 means Padding Top 4, Padding Bottom 4, Padding Right 4, Padding Left 4)
- top and bottom of each shape is represented by a number 1 which is equivalent to "-" dash letter when is drawn
- right and left side of each shape is represented by a number 2 which is equivalent to "|" pipe letter when is drawn
- other areas are space is represented by a number 0 which is equivalent to " " space letter when is drawn

I was able to draw the outside box but couldn't do the recursive box inside the array and my code is

```
function draw(width, height, padding){
   return Array.from({length: width}, (_, row) => {
    return Array.from({length: height}, (_, col) => {
        if(width < padding/2 || height < padding/2){
          return;
        }
        if(row === 0 || row === width - 1 ){ return 1; }
        if(col === 0 || col === height - 1){ return 2; }
        return 0;
      })
    });
  }
console.log(draw(20,20,4));
```

Demo in action which I want to replicate in JS
https://infinite-peaceful-stream.herokuapp.com/draw.php

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell if you're looking for a full solution.  That site looks as though it's supposed to be a learning site.  Here is some code that might help you work on the interesting, recursive part of the solution.

The important thing here is the function `layer`, which accepts two encoded images and creates a new one by placing the `upper` one atop the `lower` one at the given `x`/`y` offsets.  The other functions here are just to make it easy to demonstrate, parsing and displaying the array of values as strings.

Obviously, I'm choosing to use `"-"`, `"|"`, and `" "` in place of your `"1"`, `"2"` and `"0"`.  It's much easier for testing, IMHO, and will be very easy to change later.  The only place this matters is in the expression `(upper [i - y] [j - x] !== ' ')`

```js
const layer = (lower, upper, x, y, h = upper .length, w = upper [0] .length) => 
  lower .map (
    (row, i) => row .map (
      (col, j) => (i >= y && i - y < h) && 
                  (j >= x && j - x < w) && 
                  (upper [i - y] [j - x] !== ' ') 
        ? upper [i - y] [j - x]
        : lower [i] [j]
    )
  )

const show = (graph) => console .log (
  graph .map (s => s .join ('')) .join ('\n')
)

const parse = ss => ss .map (s => s.split(''))

const lower = parse ([
  '---------------------',
  '|                   |',
  '|                   |',
  '|                   |',
  '|                   |',
  '|                   |',
  '---------------------',
])

const upper = parse ([
  '------',
  '| 42 |',
  '------',
])

show (layer (lower, upper, 5, 2)) //=>
// ---------------------
// |                   |
// |    ------         |
// |    | 42 |         |
// |    ------         |
// |                   |
// ---------------------

show (layer (lower, upper, 12, 3)) //=>
// ---------------------
// |                   |
// |                   |
// |           ------  |
// |           | 42 |  |
// |           ------  |
// ---------------------

show (layer (lower, upper, 1, 1)) //=>
// ---------------------
// |------             |
// || 42 |             |
// |------             |
// |                   |
// |                   |
// ---------------------
```

### Edit

As others are posting full solutions here, I'll include mine, which takes the recursive structure more seriously.

```js
const border = (x, y) => 
  [... Array (y)] .map ((_, i) => [...Array (x)] .map (
    (_, j) =>  i == 0 || i == y - 1 ? '1' : j == 0 || j == x - 1 ? '2' : '0' 
  ))

const draw = (w, h, p, hp = Math .floor (p / 2)) =>
  h <= p || w <= p   
    ? border(w, h)
  : layer (border (w, h), draw (w - p, h - p, p), hp, hp)

const layer = (lower, upper, x, y, h = upper .length, w = upper [0] .length) => 
  lower .map (
    (row, i) => row .map (
      (col, j) => (i >= y && i - y < h) && 
                  (j >= x && j - x < w) && 
                  (upper [i - y] [j - x] !== 0) 
        ? upper [i - y] [j - x]
        : lower [i] [j]
    )
  )

const show = (graph) => console .log (graph .map (ns => ns .join ('')) .join ('\n'), '', graph .map (ns => ns .join ('').replace(/1/g, '-').replace(/2/g, '|').replace(/0/g, ' ')) .join ('\n'))


show (draw (40, 20, 4))
```

`layer` is as above, `border` creates an encoded image containing the outer border, and the main function `draw` handles recurring inward until there is no room left.  (I did switch to the required `0`, `1`, `2` in these.)  `show` simply displays the result, both with digits and in ASCII art.

**Note**, though, that although I like this breakdown of the problem, the solution from Nina Scholz is overall simpler.  I would choose that one unless I was mostly interested in the basic recursion.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an interactive snippet that responds to changes in the three arguments:

I kept your idea of using arrays with 0, 1 and 2, and only convert that matrix to a string at the latest moment. But you could of course choose to generate the final characters immediately:

```js
function draw(width, height, padding) {
    if (width <= padding+2 || height <= padding+2) { // Base case: innermost rectangle
        if (width <= 0 || height <= 0) return [];
        if (height < 2) return [Array(width).fill(1)];
        return [
            Array(width).fill(1),
            ...Array.from({length: height-2}, () => width < 2 ? [2] : [2, ...Array(width-2).fill(0), 2]),
            Array(width).fill(1),
        ];
    }
    return [
        Array(width).fill(1),
        ...Array.from({length: padding>>1}, () => [2, ...Array(width-2).fill(0), 2]),
        ...draw(width - padding - 2, height - padding - 2, padding).map((row,i) => 
            [2, ...Array(padding>>1).fill(0), ...row, ...Array(padding>>1).fill(0), 2]
        ),
        ...Array.from({length: padding>>1}, () => [2, ...Array(width-2).fill(0), 2]),
        Array(width).fill(1)
    ];
}

// I/O handling
let inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input"));
let output = document.querySelector("pre");
document.addEventListener("input", refresh);

function refresh() {
    // Get input values
    let [width, height, padding] = inputs.map(input => Math.max(0, Math.round(+input.value)));
    padding = padding - (padding % 2); // Make sure it is a multiple of 2.
    let matrix = draw(width, height, padding);
    // Convert matrix of 0, 1, 2 to string
    output.textContent = matrix.map(row => row.map(i => " -|"[i]).join``).join`\n`;
}
refresh();
```

```css
input { width: 4em }
pre { font-size: 8px }
```

```html
Width: <input type="number" value="70">
Height: <input type="number" value="16">
Padding: <input type="number" value="2" step="2">
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a simplified approach by using only the nice part of the calculation for the easy quadrant of the array (you know, if you have a look to the first version).

For keeping the wanted pattern, a singl value is inportant, which describes the relation between a line and the space between.

In this case, with `padding` of `4`, you get the value of `3`, because `1` for the line itselft and `2`, the half of `padding` for the soave between two lines.

This value is called `delta` and has a value of `3`, the sum `1 + 2`.

> You could take an approach which respects the quadrants
>
> ```
> AB
> CD
> ```
>
> by using only the left upper A quadrant.
>
> ```
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . .
> 2                   . . . . . . . . . .
> 2                   . . . . . . . . . .
> 2     1 1 1 1 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . .
> 2     2             . . . . . . . . . .
> 2     2             . . . . . . . . . .
> 2     2     1 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . .
> 2     2     2       . . . . . . . . . .
> 2     2     2       . . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
> ```
>
> All other index position are calculated, if greater than the half of `width` or `height`. Then it takes the count from the right/bottom side.
>
> The final calculation is done with a delta of the size of a line (1) and the half of the padding. For getting if a line/dot is found, you could take the remainder and check if the value is zero and if the direction is right.
>
> A small look to the result of direction check
>
> ```
> row <= col // 1
> col <= row // 2
> ```
>
> shows,
>
> ```
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . .
> 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . .
> 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . .
> 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . .
> 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . .
> 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . .
> 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . .
> 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . .
> 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 . . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
> ```
>
> which is exactly the shape, we need to get the right values which are like shining from the center of the array.
>
> Together with the pattern check and the direction check
>
> ```
> if (row % delta === 0 && row <= col) return 1;
> if (col % delta === 0 && col <= row) return 2;
> ```

```js
function draw(width, height, padding) {
    var delta = 1 + padding / 2;

    return Array.from({ length: height }, (_, row) => {
        if (row >= height / 2) row = height - row - 1;
        return Array.from({ length: width }, (_, col) => {
            if (col >= width / 2) col = width - col - 1;

            if (row % delta === 0 && row <= col) return 1;
            if (col % delta === 0 && col <= row) return 2;

            return ' ';
        });
    });
}

var result = draw(20, 18, 4);

result.forEach(a => console.log(a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is quite nice.  I thought that anything not recursive would require lots of obnoxious fiddling with numbers.  Your `delta` cleans that up entirely, and this version has less fiddling than my recursive one!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach by recurrence. Just take an anchor, draw the rectangle. And call yourself back with the translated anchor (according to padding)

```js
function draw(w,h,p){
    function fill({x,y}, w, h){
        if(w < 1 || h < 1){return M}
        for(let i=x; i < x+h; ++i){
            M[i][y] = 2;
            M[i][y+w-1] = 2;
        }
        for(let j=y; j < y+w; ++j){
            M[x][j] = 1;
            M[x+h-1][j] = 1;
        }
        //-p-2 to remove padding and the current borders
        return fill({x:x+p/2+1, y:y+p/2+1}, w-p-2, h-p-2)
    }
    let M = Array(h).fill(0).map(x=>Array(w).fill(0));
    return fill({x:0,y:0}, w, h);
}
console.log(draw(20,20,4).map(x=>x.join('')).join('\n'))
console.log(draw(5,5,2).map(x=>x.join('')).join('\n'))
```